# Array List Taking only One element

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist

HI I am trying to execute the following code snippet

```
        dim lst(10) as string
        dim arlist As New ArrayList
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            lst(0) = dr(0).ToString()
            lst(1) = dr(1).ToString()
            lst(2) = dr(2).ToString()
            lst(3) = dr(3).ToString()
            lst(4) = dr(4).ToString()
            lst(5) = dr(5).ToString()
            lst(6) = dr(6).ToString()
            lst(7) = dr(7).ToString()
            lst(8) = dr(8).ToString()
            lst(9) = dr(9).ToString()
            lst(10) = dr(10).ToString()
            arlist.Add(lst)
        End While
        dr.Close()
```

But at the end in the array list 'arlist' I am getting only one element repeated

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBiEZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the reference of the current instance of the `lst` is added to the `ArrayList` so the modification you made in the lst will affect in the ArrayList too. And hence you will get the Last value repeated in all index of the arrayList. What you can do is, define the `lst` inside the loop as like the following:

```
Dim arlist As New ArrayList
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While dr.Read()
    Dim lst(10) as string
    lst(0) = dr(0).ToString()
    lst(1) = dr(1).ToString()
    '> Rest of elements    
    arlist.Add(lst)
End While
dr.Close()
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LPuZ1q) you can find a working example